# ¿Cómo agregar imágenes dentro del directorio res/drawable con Android?

Tags: java, android

Estoy desarrollando una app en Android con la cual descargo un catálogo de imágenes de un servidor utilizando un API REST y lo que quiero hacer es guardar dichas imágenes dentro del directorio `res/drawable` de tal manera que pueda utilizarlas en cualquier momento para cargarlas dentro de un `ImageView` de la siguiente manera:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.your_image_field_id);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_icon_name);
```

Para obtener las imágenes del servidor utilizo un `AsyncTask` y las imágenes se van almacenando en un `ArrayList<Bitmap>`, el código utilizado es el que se muestra a continuación, nótese que algunas variables son globales:

```
private ArrayList<Corte> cortes = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Bitmap> iconos = new ArrayList<>();

private void adaptadorCorteAddItems(boolean informacionRemota) {
    ArrayList<Corte> informacion = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Corte> cortesSQLite = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Bitmap> imagenes = new ArrayList<>();

    if (informacionRemota) {
        try {
           informacion = new CorteAsyncTask(getActivity(), 22).execute(
                    "skip", String.valueOf(cortes.size()),
                    "limit", String.valueOf(limit),
                    "genero", String.valueOf(idGenero),
                    "clasificacion", String.valueOf(idClasificacion),
                    "sort", "tamano"
            ).get();
            for (Corte dato : informacion) {
                imagenes.add(new ImagenAsyncTask(getActivity()).execute(dato.getOriginalPhoto()).get());
            }
            if (informacion.size() > 0) {
                cortes.addAll(informacion);
                iconos.addAll(imagenes);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        }
    } else {
        if (adaptadorCorte.getItemCount() == 0) {
            informacion.addAll(cortes);
            imagenes.addAll(iconos);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Para ayudarte mejor, necesitamos saber que es lo que ya  tienes hecho. Te recomiendo que puedas ver este [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para saber como poner tu codigo. Al hacer esto podremos ayudarte mejor y de seguro obtendras una respuesta.

Comment: No se puede escribir en res / drawable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Los directorios de recursos del sistema de como son:  `/drawable`, `/mipmap`, `/raw`, `/assets`, etc, son directorios de solo lectura por lo tanto no se puede escribir dentro de ellos.**

Regularmente cuando se obtiene un recurso externo y este necesita ser almacenado, esto se realiza en el directorio de almacenamiento externo o la SDcard.

Te recomiendo guardar las imagenes, ejemplo:

```
URL url = new URL ("http://mydomain.com/imagen.png"); 
String storagePath = "/imagenes/";
InputStream input = url.openStream(); 
try {     
    File storagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream (storagePath, "imagen_guardada.png");     
    try {         
        byte[] buffer = new byte[aReasonableSize];         
        int bytesRead = 0;         
        while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) >= 0) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);         
        }     
    }   
    finally {         
        output.close();     
    } 
} finally {     
    input.close(); 
}
```

Para obtener el bitmap de la imagen y usarla en tu `ImageView` se realizaría de esta forma:

```
String storagePath = "/imagenes/";
String photoPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ storagePath + "imagen_guardada.png";

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Jorgesys, después de tu aportación revisé un poco la documentación oficial de Android en cuanto a almacenamiento de la información se refiere y veo que hacer eso seria la solución a mi problema. Gracias a todos por la retroalimentación.